# Can I change the sender name for sending email in MVC .net Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp

I have the following code.Now I don't want to display my email address as sender address instead I need a friendly name. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
smtpServer.Port = 587;

mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("recepient@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Password recovery";
mail.Body = "Recovering the password";

smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Can I change the mail.From??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below.

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com","Your display name");
```

OR

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMesage(
    new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Your display Name"),
));
```